# Cannot process POST requests in the Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am setting my express with PUG. The get requests are working without any issue but the posts requests do not seem to work.

The code is simple. I have tried many times but I can not figure it out.

here is the express code.

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 



app.set('view engine', 'pug'); 
app.set('views', __dirname + '\\views');


app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render('continue')
})
app.post('/submit',function(req,res){
     res.redirect('http://www.google.com')
})
app.listen(3000);
```

the pug code is here.

```html
head
title welcome
body
form(action="/submit", method='post')
input(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

I should be redirected to google after clicking the button but it does not work.

Comment: `pug` is sensitive of indentation. Adjust your `pug` template with proper indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **pug** source code, the input tag is not a child element of the form tag based on the indentation. Indent the `input()` line to place the submit button inside of the form. It doesn't appear to be necessary but I recommend indenting the `form()` line once and indenting the `input()` line twice to show that these elements are children of `body`.

```
head
  title welcome
body
  form(action="/submit", method='post')
    input(type='submit' value='Submit')
```